# Switching between different content in the layout file in Laravel/Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I recently started to build a Laravel/blade web application and I want to switch between what my layout view is showing. I want to replace `'content'` with some other blade.php view when I press a button in the layout file. For example in ReactJS you can just determine the rendered content with an IF statement and some vars.

```
 <div class="container">
   @yield ('content')
 </div>
```

I googled a bit but couldn't find a straight forward solution so I wondered if this is common in Laravel or do you just have to make a lot of different layout files with other `@yield('...')`? A lot of code would be duplicated right?

Comment: In Laravel, what you've defined is a layout. You can extend the layout by using the blade directive @extends and defining the section by using @section('content')

You can further read here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#defining-a-layout

Comment: So, inside the @section('content') I can create a switch function which determines what the user is going to see?

Comment: So I assume I got you wrong, you can use your switch case as you planned but then you should use @include, read more here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#including-sub-views

Comment: When you press a button in a layout file, make it go to a Laravel route. Do some processing on controller end and then return the view you want to show. In that view, just add `@extends('layout')` at the top and add `@section('content')` and add the html you want to show under that section.

Comment: I think you wanted to achieve something like, a button to list items as list and icons. If that's the case, you can set a session variable which will be updated each time you click on the change layout button. Then in your view file, you can check that session variable to determine which layout (design) should be used.

Answer (score -1):

You can use conditional blade directives

```
@if(Session::get(user_type') == 'Admin')
@extends('layouts.admin')
@else
    @extends('layouts.normal')  
@endif

@section('title')

@endsection

@section('content')
```

etc ....